# Python "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" why?

Tags: python

My formatting is terrible. Screenshot is here:

[image]

```py
n = int(input("enter the number of Fibonacci sequence you want. ")
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
count = 0

if n <= 0:
  print("please enter a postive integer")
elif n == 1:
  print("Fibonacci sequence:")
  print(n1)

else:
  while count < n:
     print(n1)
     nth = n1 + n2
     n1 = n2
     n2 = nth
     count = count + 1
```

I cannot figure out why do I get this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-68-9c2ad055a726>", line 3
    n1 = 0
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Always try to check above line too when you got error on specific SyntaxError,
You simply forgot to close your `)` close breaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ')' is missing in first line i guess, that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

When such error arises, do check for the preceding line also. There are very high chances of error being in the preceding line, as in this case. There's a `)` missing in the input line. You closed 1 `)` for the input() function, but did not close for `int` constructor.